# How to make requests with HessianKit

Tags: ios, hessian

I am working on an ios app that needs to connect to a hessian service to get live stock prices.  I am using HessianKit for ios.

I was told to connect to:
http://www.ourserviceurl.com:8080/tt/sub?hessian=true&tickers=BA|C

tickers is a pipe delimited list.
i had to hide the name of the url as well.

My protocol is:

```
@protocol CWHelloService
    -(NSString*)sub:(BOOL)hessian tickers:(NSString *)tickers;
@end
```

I tried to connect this way:

```
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.ourserviceurl.com:8080/tt/"];
id<CWHelloService> proxy = (id<CWHelloService>)[CWHessianConnection proxyWithURL:url protocol:@protocol(CWHelloService)];
NSLog(@"hello: %@", [proxy sub:YES tickers:@"BA|C"]);
```

I keep getting a 404 error when trying to make the connection.

I have never used the hessian protocol before and I am sure I am missing something simple, but still can't figure out where I am going wrong

Answer (score 0):

i was just informed that we are using the hessian streaming protocol and that this isn't supported by the various hessian apis that are out there right now.  As of right now it seems like the problem is unresolvable.